# Couchbase .Net Library complex startKey/endKey types

Tags: c#, .net, rest, couchbase

I need to convert those params from REST-API query to C# LINQ.

> ?descending=true&endkey=[35,37]&startkey=[35,37,{}]

In LINQ this query look like this:

> c.GetView("MyView", "SubView").StartKey(startKey).EndKey(endKey).Descending(true);

What type should be variables startKey and endKey?

I've tried string, but in this case .Net library produces query with invalid params:

> ?descending=true&endkey="[35,37]"&startkey="[35,37,{}]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some research and found the answer. Acording to https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/master/src/Couchbase/CouchbaseViewBase.cs#L320

I've finally find types for my LINQ variables:

> object[] startKey = new object[] { 35, 37, "{}" };
>
> object[] endKey = new object[] { 35, 37};

and query:
>

> c.GetView("MyView", "SubView").StartKey(startKey).EndKey(endKey).Descending(true);