# Couchbase queries using composite keys in F#

Tags: f#, couchbase

How would one translate the following composite key query:

```
?stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0&startkey=["Default",{}]&endkey=["Default"]&descending=true
```

to couchbase .net api when using F#. I found a similar using C# LINQ here
[Couchbase .Net Library complex startKey/endKey types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140751/couchbase-net-library-complex-startkey-endkey-types/11154008#11154008), but how can I accomplish the same using F#?

The missing parts are the ???

```
let result = myView.Descending(true).Stale(StaleMode.False).Limit(limit).StartKey( ??? ).EndKey( ??? )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're asking how to create an array in F#.  To declare an object array in F# do this:

```
let (startKey: Object array) = [|35; 23; new Object()|]
let (endKey: Object array) = [|35; 23|]
```

Note that normally the type specification isn't needed, but since you're mixing types in the array, the compiler will assume the type of the first object in the array (int) and so the `new Object()` would cause a compile error.  Adding the type specification fixes that issue.

```
let result = myView.Descending(true).Stale(StaleMode.False).Limit(limit).StartKey( startKey ).EndKey( endKey )
```

Comment: You are almost correct. The "{}" will actually serialize as json string and not as an empty object which is just {}. The proper way to match the query would be: [|"Default"; new Object()|]

I was not aware of type specification on arrays, thank you.

Please modify the answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I actually just stole the arrays from the other question you linked.  Happy to change it to an `Object` though.